# Why doesn't Gai use ninjutsu or genjutsu more often?

Tags: naruto

According to the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Might_Guy), Gai is able to use ninjutsu and genjutsu, so why doesn't he use it?

Comment: I think it's because he wants to support Lee!

Comment: That would be my guess too. But he doesn't use them even when Lee isn't around.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say because they aren't his strengths - clearly **Taijutsu** is so why should he use something that he isn't great at?

It could also be that he has used them in the past and it, unfortunately, got him into some difficulty so he had to fall back on the tried and tested techniques of his **Taijutsu** :)

Answer (score 0):

Gai is based off of Bruce Lee, and Bruce Lee was known for his extraordinary fighting skills (taijutsu in this case). Furthermore, Gai is known as the best taijutsu shinobi in Konoha.

Thus, it would only make sense to accentuate Gai's physical prowess and focus less on genjutsu / ninjutsu.